# touchesBegan on UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, xcode5, touchesbegan

I'd like to make appear an image during specific period when keep touching on regarding uitableviewcell (like snapchat).

I'm trying to implement touchesBegan method but doesn't work. It will be great if anyone give me an advice & idea about how can I implement or which object should I use.

Answer (score 2):

When you touch the a cell, it becomes highlighted; try overriding `setHighlighted:` in a subclass of UITableViewCell to adjust your appearance when it changes to YES (user touching) or NO (user lifted off).

(Overriding `touchesBegan:withEvent:` will also work, but it's easier to use `setHighlighted:` in order to capture when you're not longer touching; otherwise you need to override `touchesEnded:withEvent:` and `touchesCancelled:withEvent:`).

Comment: Dear Sanjay, I defined an UILongPressGestureRecognizer on cellForRowAtIndexPath, call a method on selector and did make my implementation. Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Do you mean for setHighlighte: ? I'll let you know when I try the method on another project.